# How to show logo only in homepage?

Tags: css, wordpress

In my [site](http://authenticvisuals.com/) want to make logo to show only on homepage. I tryed this CSS:

```
#header-logo #logo .page-id-7  {
display: none !important;
}
```

to remove logo in this [page](http://authenticvisuals.com/what-we-do/), but seems that dont worked at all.. Logo is still there. Anyone to help me, how to show logo only in homepage. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since .page-id-7 is a class of the body tag, you should start with that.

```
.page-id-7 #header-logo #logo{
    display:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

More universal solution

```
if ( is_home() ) {
  //Display Logo
} else {
  //Don't
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have a "home" class, why don't use this instead of the id?

```
#logo {
    display: none;
}
.home #logo  {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Dora wants to display the logo ONLY on the homepage.. page-id-7 is correct

Comment: ahh. I have changed my answer.